# How to keep track of activities in activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to keep track of all activities in the activity stack. Does anyone know how to do this from code?

Comment: "I need to keep track of currently existed Activities in Activity stack" -- why?

Comment: Why not? He didn't ask for design advice, just wanted to know how to do it. I don't think it should be forbidden knowledge.

Comment: @JakeBasile Did you ever get to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep a track of activity stack...
But there is a way to manipulate the stack using intent flags. 
Example:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This flag will clear all the activites, from the stack, present above MainActivity, and launch MaintActivity.
There are other flags to manipulate the stack as well..
Hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

Pretty much what CommonsWare said. Pretty much any reason to do this is wrong. If you think you need to do it, just stop and ask yourself if it's really needed. Messing with the activity stack in any way will just annoy the user and cause problems for you and them.

Comment: This is unhelpful. The question didn't state why because it doesn't matter. Maybe he just wants to research how it works?